# How to plot shaded error bands with seaborn?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I wish to create a plot like the following, where I show some values alongside standard deviations.

[image]

I have two sets of values, containing the mean and standard deviation obtained by two different methods. I thought of doing this with [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html), but I don't know exactly how to do it since the [official example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/errorband_lineplots.html) uses pandas DataFrame objects, which I'm not familiar with.

As an example, consider the following starting code:

```
import seaborn as sns

mean_1 = [10, 20, 30, 25, 32, 43]
std_1 = [2.2, 2.3, 1.2, 2.2, 1.8, 3.5]

mean_2 = [12, 22, 30, 13, 33, 39]
std_2 = [2.4, 1.3, 2.2, 1.2, 1.9, 3.5]
```

Thank you,

G.

Comment: You don't need a dataframe, but you do need the raw data to use seaborn. If you've already computed your stats, you need to use the `plot` and `fill_between` methods in matplotlib directly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) can you show me an example, please?

Comment: there are examples of using `plot` and `fill_between` all over this website and matplotlib.org

Comment: The example shown above, which is provided by seaborn in the documentation doesn't make any sense. The parameters passed are the x values, y values, and then values for the style and hue. There is no parameter there for the width of the shaded region. Either something is happening which I don't understand, because it hasn't been explained in the docs, or the example they provide is just wrong. I have seen the page where you got the above figure from.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is a minimal example to create such a plot with the given data. Thanks to [vectorization and broadcasting](https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/), working with numpy simplifies the code.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mean_1 = np.array([10, 20, 30, 25, 32, 43])
std_1 = np.array([2.2, 2.3, 1.2, 2.2, 1.8, 3.5])

mean_2 = np.array([12, 22, 30, 13, 33, 39])
std_2 = np.array([2.4, 1.3, 2.2, 1.2, 1.9, 3.5])

x = np.arange(len(mean_1))
plt.plot(x, mean_1, 'b-', label='mean_1')
plt.fill_between(x, mean_1 - std_1, mean_1 + std_1, color='b', alpha=0.2)
plt.plot(x, mean_2, 'r-', label='mean_2')
plt.fill_between(x, mean_2 - std_2, mean_2 + std_2, color='r', alpha=0.2)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Another example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
N = 100
x = np.arange(N)
mean_1 = 25 + np.random.normal(0.1, 1, N).cumsum()
std_1 = 3 + np.random.normal(0, .08, N).cumsum()

mean_2 = 15 + np.random.normal(0.2, 1, N).cumsum()
std_2 = 4 + np.random.normal(0, .1, N).cumsum()

plt.plot(x, mean_1, 'b-', label='mean_1')
plt.fill_between(x, mean_1 - std_1, mean_1 + std_1, color='b', alpha=0.2)
plt.plot(x, mean_2, 'r--', label='mean_2')
plt.fill_between(x, mean_2 - std_2, mean_2 + std_2, color='r', alpha=0.2)

plt.legend(title='title')
plt.show()
```

[image: second example]

PS: Using matplotlib 3.5 or higher, the line and the fill can be combined in the legend:

```py
line_1, = plt.plot(x, mean_1, 'b-')
fill_1 = plt.fill_between(x, mean_1 - std_1, mean_1 + std_1, color='b', alpha=0.2)
line_2, = plt.plot(x, mean_2, 'r--')
fill_2 = plt.fill_between(x, mean_2 - std_2, mean_2 + std_2, color='r', alpha=0.2)
plt.margins(x=0)

plt.legend([(line_1, fill_1), (line_2, fill_2)], ['Series 1', 'Series 2'], title='title')
```

[image: combining line and fill in the legend]

Comment: Legend may include the "fill" command related series. If this is the case you can add after `alpha=0.2` the following parameter `label='_nolegend_'` in the respective lines. This way you can write `plt.legend(['S1','S2'])`   for each series only.

Comment: @FilipePinto Thanks for the tip.  I added an example to the post.