# How to show shaded error bands when the data is in two different dataframes?

Tags: dataframe, plot, standard-deviation

I want to plot a line graph with shaded error bands across this line. My data is in two different data frames. First dataframe, as shown below, has mean and the positive error is mean + stdev, negative error is mean - stdev. A different dataframe has x-axis  as the column against which I want to plot mean and error bands.

| ​a | b | mean | stdev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.05 | 0.06 | 0.055 | 0.007 |
| 0.1 | 0.13 | 0.115 | 0.02 |
| -0.2 | -0.5 | -0.35 | 0.21 |

I found few discussions on how to do this with lists and arrays but nothing with dataframes.
[How to plot shaded error bands with seaborn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61368805/how-to-plot-shaded-error-bands-with-seaborn)

Comment: You can convert column to list with `mean_list = df['mean'].tolist()`.

Comment: I ended up saving all the required columns as series and used ax.fill_between to show the shaded area.